# Create/Save through relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have the following models:

- User
- Device
- Group

Below are the relationships:

`User belongsTo a group`

`Group hasMany Users`

`Device belongsTo group`

How can i create a `Device` through user?

```
$user = Auth::user();

$new_device = new Device;
$new_device->ip = $request->input('ip');
$new_device->port = $request->input('port');
$new_device->community_name = $request->input('community_name');

$user->group->save($new_device);
```

Error I am getting when using:

`$user->group->save($new_device);`

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/snmpexperiments/laravel/app/Http/Controllers/SnmpController.php on line 74
```

Error I am getting when using:

`$user->group()->save($new_device);`

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::save()
```

I am kind of confused..should i save the device through the group or should i save the device through user?

> User Model

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}

public function devices()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Device', 'App\Group'); // So i can get devices like $user->devices
}
```

> Group Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function devices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Device');
}

public function interfaces(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ModelInterface', 'App\Device'); // So I can get interfaces through Device $group->interfaces
}
```

> Device Model

```
public function interfaces()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ModelInterface');
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is `$post->comments()->save($comment);`. Note the parenthesis after comments, which accesses the relationship method instead of the property. So in this case you would use

```
$user->group->devices()->save($new_device);
```

Comment: Thanks...i will accept the answer in 3 minutes. So, when should i use the parenthesis and when not to? If the relation is belongsTo then it is considered a property?

Comment: I tend to be a little fuzzy on it, but if you're retrieving a property, or the relationships, don't use the parenthesis. If you're using an extended method or extending the query builder, then use the parenthesis.

Comment: Ok i used `dump($user->group())` and it showed the relationship belongsTo - but when I used `dump($user->group)` it returned the actual group model. Thanks a lot for the guidance and time.

Answer (score 0):

To save the device through group you would need to specify device.

```
$user->group->device()->save($new_device);
```

The way you are doing it your trying to save the group model. The model->save() can accept an array of options that's why you are getting that error.